# Is it possible to make a "good" options dialog?

Tags: gui-design, dialog, options

One thing I'm struggling with, and have yet to see an example I'm happy with, is an options dialog (in a desktop app, if that makes any difference.) I'm having difficulties with my own, but they all seem to have the same problems. To take a more generic example:

[image: Microsoft Word options dialog]

There's a few common problems that I see:

- Discoverability is poor; even when grouping into categories. The most common method of finding something in an options dialog seems to be Googling what to click on!
- Grouping is poor - the "Advanced" tab seems to be a huge culmination of "I don't know where this goes".
- Explanation of individual functionality is poor in many cases, as it would require a lengthy explanation that doesn't fit on the label.
- Not to do with the above screenshot, but they're not even named or launched consistently. Years ago, it always seemed to be Tools -> Options. These days it seems it's either under the "Tools", "File" or "Edit" menus for those apps that still use traditional menus, and could be called "Options", "Preferences", "Settings", or anything else vaguely relevant.

Some of the better "options" screens I've seen are those in browsers; Chrome for example allows you to search, which arguably improves the discoverability:

[image: Chrome options]

However, even in this case you have to search for the exact phrase or word that you're after. Searching for "Do not track" for example will get you the option to send a "Do not track" request. Searching for "disable tracking" will leave you empty-handed.

The solutions that I can think of aren't really feasible:

- Slim down the options dialog and put only the most common options there (it always starts small, but many of the options present are there at user request!)
- Do without the options dialog and find other places to put customisation, such as a toolbar or ribbon (anecdotal, but I've found this just makes it even more annoying to find what you need);
- Use help icons for longer explanations of option functionality (surely no-one would actually use them?)
- Create more categories to get rid of an "Advanced" or "General" category (then you just end up with a whole heap of categories you can't really navigate, some of which only have one option in them.)

Are there any good examples that I'm missing, any known solutions to these problems, or any relevant literature in the field for creating an options dialog that doesn't completely suck?

Comment: Here's a related question (with answer): https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/115208/research-and-guidelines-for-settings-menus-and-control-panels

Comment: In Firefox, the options dialog is already a slimmed down version compared to about:preferences :)

Comment: Tangentially related: Please allow to export and reimport your settings. A lot of apps don't allow that, and it is really a pain when you have to spend hours searching again for _that one_ option.

Comment: Whatever you do, use a plain text format config file. Then you can just document your "advanced options" and have people edit them using a text editor.

Comment: @lilpu That's exactly what we do at the moment for some options, but it seems like there should be a better way of solving this in the actual interface.

Comment: For the explanations: Tooltips! (:

Comment: Do you have a mac? Afaik on a mac you can search for every option that is in the toolbar or the options menu. And having a good search is a hard problem either. It's not a coincidence that google is a rich company. I think having a page that can be googled or looked up is the best you can do. Maybe include the html sites in the application itself and make them open with the standard browser or something.

Comment: @seaturtle Tooltips seemed like an initially good idea to me too, but they're a pain if you're scrolling down to see which option you want - you'd have to hover and read the explanation on every one of them just to check.

Comment: @DrakaSAN cloud sync!

Comment: @virtualnobi that question has a further [related question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/48214/best-layout-for-a-settings-page)

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga And what happens if I don't have access to Internet on both devices, or access to the device with the original settings? Or if the sync happens in the wrong way? I prefer low level access anytime

Comment: @DrakaSAN No internet? Import/export to/from file. Cloud sync should be optional and prompt the user in exceptional cases (and support reverts).

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga Well, exporting to a text file have the pro of being way easier to implement, after that, it is a matter of taste, and ours differs on that point :)

Comment: Regarding the launching of the options/setting page -> in macOS, in most apps, you open the settings page by a keyboard shortcut cmd+, and you don't need to worry where is it hidden;)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Software development IDEs have some of the most complicated settings pages I've ever seen, and IntelliJ IDEA does a great job with discoverability. Not only do they offer a search to narrow down the left "tree" to matching pages, they also have a special highlighting effect for matching options. This is similar to your Chrome example, but even better since it doesn't lose the original layout and hierarchy of the unfiltered options.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA settings dialog filtered to Scala]

## To your solutions:

(All quotes are from the OP)

> - Slim down the options dialog and put only the most common options there (it always starts small, but many of the options present are there at user request!)

Please don't slim down too much! certainly you could make a "common" settings page but we power users hate it when there's no way at all to change something

> - Do without the options dialog and find other places to put customisation, such as a toolbar or ribbon (anecdotal, but I've found this just makes it even more annoying to find what you need);

This is always good practice, but *in addition* to the options/settings dialog. It should be a one stop shop for all customization of the software.

> - Use help icons for longer explanations of option functionality (surely no-one would actually use them?)

I think people would use them, and more importantly, it would be additional text that could be matched by the filter at the top of the dialog. If the option was "Export to CSV" and the help text was "Export files to comma-delimited files that can be opened in Microsoft Excel", then that allows for queries "csv" and "excel" to match that option.

> - Create more categories to get rid of an "Advanced" or "General" category (then you just end up with a whole heap of categories you can't really navigate, some of which only have one option in them.)

Yes, to an extent- no categories with one option, but removing "General" and "Advance" and organize in a tree (if there are too many for a simple list like Firefox or your Word example).

Comment: I love that the accepted answer references IntelliJ. First thing I thought of when reading this question. +1

Comment: I'm actually a bit miffed with myself that I missed this as an option when first asking the question - I use IntelliJ near daily! The IntelliJ style option search, coupled with additional text that could be matched with a search filter, could well be the best answer I've seen to this issue.

Comment: I'd also like to draw attention to FrankerFaceZ for an example of including extra explanatory text with settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvMd8.png Of course, this makes for extra translation work. (They also have a stacked / conditional config system.)

Comment: What's ironic about this answer is that I much prefer Eclipse over IntelliJ, but IntelliJ wins the Options Dialog battle, hands down!

Comment: As a user, I've become a big fan of help tooltips containing (a) brief explanatory text, or examples, etc, and (b) a clickable link into the appropriate online reference.  Whether those tooltips are activated by mousing over the option checkbox itself, or a dedicated "?"-type icon to the side, whatever.  I'm **not** a fan of the "one 'help' icon for the entire window" style such as the MS-Outlook example in the OP, because God only knows what's going to happen when I click it.

Comment: Advanced and General (and Common) categories do indeed need to go. How is a user supposed to know if a programmer decided an option is “advanced,” “common,” or “general”? Instead, I wonder if it makes sense to use bold font or other emphasis for more frequently set options wherever they are so the eye tends to fall on them. Putting them first in their respective sections would very likely help too.

Comment: @TiStrga based on my experience, that help icon almost always pops up an "I wish I was a real web browser" side panel that allows you to browse Outlook's online help, but with 1/8th the screen real estate. I don't understand why that's an improvement over just googling it. Though my version of Outlook doesn't even have the ? button on the settings window.

Comment: I was going to say it's odd to commend IntelliJ for exactly copying Eclipse, but then I realised the highlighting was part of the actual dialog box and not image editing.

Comment: +1 to IntelliJ settings pages. I can't think of any better example. I would +1 again for your comment on help icons if I could. I very often use them when they are available because quite frankly, they are often *necessary*. And yes, if the help icon's text content can be searched as well, it solves the problem of needing the "exact phrase/term".

Answer (score 19):

**Root Cause: Implementation Driving UI**

The whole idea of a single consolidated Options dialog seems to be a consequence of programs having configuration files. The Options function would read the configuration file, present it to the user in a dialog for editing, then save the changes back the configuration file. Perhaps some other programs do the same thing, only reading and writing to the Registry. The implementation, rather than the user’s tasks, is driving the UI design, which often a bad thing. It makes it convenient for the programmer, but not the user.

With the possible exception of when a user first installs a program, a user generally doesn’t think, “Today I’ll change my options.” What happens is the program is doing something specific that isn’t what the user wants (e.g., by default pasting to match source format). So users (if they’re savvy enough) think, “Maybe there’s an option for it,” and embark on a major safari to hunt it down in a jungle of options, assuming it exists. No wonder it doesn’t work.

**Addressing Discoverability: Options Proximal to Affected Features**

The solution is to *put the options with the feature it affects*. Don’t have all options in one massive dialog. Distribute them around your menus and dialogs. For example, for changing the default pasting, the Edit menu has a Paste Options menu item below the Paste menu item. Paste Options opens a simple dialog to select the default pasting behavior. Or there’s a Paste Special dialog that includes “Make this Default” so when users select special pasting behavior for a particular instance, they can also make it permanent. This improves discoverability. Or maybe there is simply "Editing Options" if there are also options for Copy, Undo, and Delete (otherwise, your menu has nearly as many "options" menu items as all the other more important ones). When the user executes the command in its menu or ribbon tab, they see there are options for it. It reduces workload, because the users don’t have to search through a zillion irrelevant and questionably organized groups of options to find the one they need. Options are organized exactly like (with) the associated features, which the user already knows or else couldn’t be using the features.

Options by definition are preserved between sessions, so they are most appropriate for things that are very rarely changed. For this reason, it’s important not to clutter your UI with Options menu items and command buttons since they’ll get in the way of what users are usually looking for. You probably should have no more than one Options button per dialog and one Options menu item per menu or ribbon tab. That may not be as strict as it sounds. Going through MS Word’s options in your example (which is among the more extensive), I see there would be:

- A Cut/Copy/Paste Options menu item on the Home tab.
- A Format Marks Options menu item on the View tab.
- A Proofing Options menu item on the Review tab.

That’s about it.

The rest of the options are either put under an Options button in a dialog/page (like Save and Print options), or they are options that aren’t associated with a menu or dialog, so they have to be handled differently (see next paragraph).

**Addressing Inconsistent Locations: Have a Preferences Menu**

There will be some options that don’t have an associated menu or dialog box, such as “select entire word” in your example. So you still need some kind of centralized place for setting them. However, they are fewer than the total number of options, so it makes them more findable, assuming it isn't best to have the same options both proximal to their associated feature and in a centralized location to maximize their discoverability.

You are correct that there is now no standardize place for them. Microsoft had “Tools” as a standard for a while, but “Tools” is like “Advanced” –a junk drawer of things that don’t fit anywhere else. Apple’s standard of putting Options in the application menu (the menu with the name of the program) sort of makes sense given the paragraph above because these are options of the entire program, not just a specific feature.

However, my advice is to have a Preferences menu at the top level (a pulldown menu or ribbon tab). The place for options is their own place, not under any other menu or tab. This maximizes discoverability: the users see “Preferences” (or “Options,” or maybe “Customize,” depending on your users) every time they open the app. It doesn’t matter if the user is expecting Options to be under Tools or Edit or the application menu. They immediately see it at the top, and don’t bother to look anywhere else.

Space or clutter is generally not an issue especially for menu bars. After File, Edit, View, and Help, most apps don’t have a whole lot else. If there are only a few options (eight or less), the Preferences menu has toggling menu items to set them directly –there is no dialog box. If there are a lot of options, split them up into separate dialogs and access each with a separate menu item (rather than have separate tabs within a dialog). For in-between numbers of options, have a mix of toggling menu items and a dialog or two.

**Addressing Poor Explanations: Active Help**

As addition to, or perhaps as a better alternative for, a Preference menu, give Help the ability to change preferences. Take “smart paragraph selection” in your example (whatever the hell that is). A user is not going to think, “This dang smart paragraph selection! I wish I could turn it off!” They’re thinking, “This selection is doing something weird; why is that?” So they naturally go to Help to learn more. If the index and search are decent, and the content clearly written, they find out about this smart paragraph selection, and how it works. Maybe once they understand it, they want to keep it. However, if they don’t, then Help should provide the means to turn it off *right there in Help*. It doesn’t direct the user through multiple steps in an Options dialog to effect this. It’s not like users need to learn that –they’re only going to turn it off once then forget about it. Let them do it right there.

Putting options in Help means searches don’t have to match the options name exactly –it can match any part of the explanation. They can also match any synonyms, assuming your search provided for that. Users get the whole explanation, so they can better determine if it’s the option they want or not.

**And Installation?**

Consider on installation presenting the user with a list of commonly change options, showing what is default, and allowing the user to alter them right there (e.g., default folders, devices, and such). However, often users need to use a program before they discover what does or doesn't work for them. Thus, it's important to make options reasonably discoverable after installation too.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer - some great thoughts. I must admit I had gone down a similar thought train at one point, but then the inevitable question of the best contextual location to put each individual option comes up, and that requires a lot more thinking in itself!

Comment: I have found programs that put options all over the place to be less user-friendly then programs who have dedicated settings pages. Settings aren't changed often. You usually do not need to be able to change the settings ad-hoc, and for the few, rare cases you want to change them, its easier to find them if they are all in one place, instead of hunting down where in the program the ability to change them is buried. Similarly, while working with the program, menu entries that allow changing of settings are just visual clutter, need to be ignored and scrolled over while not being needed.

Comment: Take for example the "Edit" menu. The entry "Change Paste Options" ist just clutter and sits there 99.9% of the time unused, while it has to be ignored while visually scanning for the entries that are actually needed to work. You change these once, and then you are done. Especially when menus grow larger and larger in an application, cutting down clutter is important.

Comment: I love this, except for the idea of putting a setting *exclusively* under "Help". I think I'm with most users in that I have never clicked on most applications' help menus. I think I've only ever opened it when looking for a version number. I've certainly never looked there when trying to change something.
I think I feel similar to "Help" as you feel to "Options" menus: it should be available contextually.

Comment: @Polygnome I would add that in my experience, the settings you change often are basically "views", and it could be "views of the contents" or "views of the toolboxes" or whatever. And these shouldn't really be in Options, but they are quite an exception.

Comment: Some settings do change more regularly- I’m always annoyed at gedit because I have to open settings for word wrap and line number changes. That’s frustrating

Comment: As a user, I appreciate having one place to go to see what options are actually available, especially in an application that allows extensive customizability.  I wouldn't mind have direct access to certain common options in the context of what they affect, but I'd still want a central place that lets me browse all of the available options.

Comment: I rather doubt your theory that such design would be implementation-driven. Even with monolithic config files, is _very easy_ to reuse the same "write a config with these options" code from multiple dialog windows. And when the config storage is abstracted out e.g. to Registry or GSettings, there is no such thing as a monolithic config file anymore – the program always reads and writes individual settings in the first place. So your argument doesn't make sense.

Comment: @yo' I would say if you change it often, it isn't an application setting, but merely a setting for your tool. Take an image manipulation app for example. The brush options, paint color etc. clearly should not go deep into the settings page, because you change them often and that are the tools you work with. But those aren't really what I would call "application settings" (but I have no idea *what* I would actually call those).

Comment: Polygnome has a point that use-once controls should not over-clutter use-regularly controls (thanks). On the other hand, it good to encourage users to look at options now and then so they can discover ways to improve their UX. Many features requested for Office already existed, but were buried in Options (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jensenh/2006/02/07/the-expert-mode-misadventure/). Fortunately, proximal options may balance the two competing goals. Done right, they make options more visible but do not add a lot of clutter, not even for MS Word. I’ve added text above on this.

Comment: Yo’ and Tim have insightful observations and I agree with Polygnomes response. Options by definition are preserved between sessions, so they are most appropriate for things that are very rarely changed. If some users are changing something every other session (like views or word wrap), then it shouldn’t be an option. It’s a command, or part of a command, like all the other ones on the menu. One way to improve your Options dialog is to make sure all your “options” are really options.

Comment: @AgentME: Well, now you touched on an entirely new Stack Exchange question: Why does Help suck? Why can I find an answer more reliably by googling the entire internet than searching a body of content specifically populated and indexed to answer exactly the kind of question I have? What are we doing wrong?

Comment: An example of 'proximal options' are the Paste settings in Word/ Outlook. Paste with source formatting, plain text, merge formatting? Even though I need & use these controls myself, I pretty much hate this stupid UX that doesn't reliably accept keyboard shortcuts. If we take that as an example I'm somewhat skeptical of "proximal options" UX -- if you do go down this path, please try to make something pointlessly annoying.

Comment: @Thomas W: Yeah, I found myself swapping between paste with and without formatting so often that I made a macro for paste without formatting and assigned it to Ctrl-Shift-V. But with/without formatting is likely an example of something that Polygnome calls a tool _setting_, rather than an option. MS may agree since Word 2013 provides it on the Paste split button (a shortcut key would be better still). Paste options are cross-session defaults, most of which the user can override with a setting in a particular instance.

Comment: In theory you are right, but when programs make controversial "improvements", sometimes I as a user just want to go through and undo all of them at once. Hypothetically this could be remedied by the program's updater preserving settings when upgrading, but sometimes I also want to have the same setup on a fresh install on a new computer. This might also be solved by configuration export / import, but that's implying that features are never, ever removed (which is unrealistic under certain UI "reboots", look at Firefox's history for example, support for some preferences was dropped).

Comment: @MichaelZuschlag Yeah, I would not call "Paste with/without formatting" a *setting* per se, at least not an *application setting*. That more like two commands to use, or one command with two possible flavors. You obviously would not put this into a settings dialog when its something that needs to be changed often. I agree somewhat with the notion that settings dialog should contain stuff that is preserved between sessions, while everything else is not.

Comment: @MichaelZuschlag Also, proximal options and a settings dialog with *all* settings do not need to be at odds. You can have both, and might even offer the user a way to disable proximal options for certain tools.

Comment: @Polygnome, "Paste with/without formatting" is a setting if we're talking defaults (I wish I could change that "setting" in Office).  But they're also two different commands.  Often, with settings, the question is "what is the default action you wish when you click that paste button"?  That makes it a setting,  in my book.

Comment: Proximal and hover UX elements are sometimes nice, but so often they're quite obnoxious, and you're forced to fight with the thing (or find a way to disable them).  And such elements more and more often come at the expense of useability and accessibility, not to mention intuition and discoverability.

Comment: @K_foxer9 If we are talking defaults, then yes. I was thinking more about like like something you change on-the-fly, google docs for example per defaults pastes with formatting, but has a separate command to paste without formatting.

Answer (score 8):

I posted a related question recently as I have been struggling with a similar problem. From what I have mustered there is no clear and clean cut solution, as these kinds of "options" are often very contextual. 
[This article briefly covers and provides some well known examples.](http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/settings-editor/)

However, I still feel that there is much to be done in terms of design solutions for these types of menus.

**One other article, which I found to be useful,** [covers the redesign process of the Firefox Options menu.](https://medium.com/firefox-ux/whats-new-in-firefox-preferences-54391f92971a) I believe the underlining message is that we need to get our design thoughts and iterations in the face of the users and see what comes up. That is what I will be doing and I'm hoping for an unexpected "Eureka" moment.

Comment: The firefox options redesign article is great, and one I hadn't come across before - thanks for that, a good read!

Comment: You're welcome! I also found it useful.

Answer (score 5):

Grouping can be improved by drawing a line between "**Configuration**" and "**Preferences**". Everything that the user *has to configure* to get your app running should go to "Configuration". Everything optional, which can actually be a *matter of preference*, should go to "Preferences". For example, I hardly have a "preference" for the default printer (it has to be the one in the same physical office as me) or the path to my autosave folder (it has to be somewhere I always have write access).

The next step is to take a good look at your preferences. **Do they actually need to be there?** For example, I can't think of a single good reason for "Use Ctrl+Click to follow hyperlinks" to be a preference. If the user doesn't want to follow hyperlinks, all he has to do is *not to click*. Or "Use smart cursors". If they're really smart, why on Earth would I want to disable them? And if they're not that smart after all, why are they implemented at all? Bottom line, try to make your app as intuitive and easy to use as possible, and remove the option to make it less intuitive.

Finally, **learn to refuse user requests**. This may cost you some customers, but believe me - a cluttered Preferences dialog costs you just as many, only those users are not vocal about it. Next time a user asks you if you could make a *smart* cursor which magically jumps to the other screen when the user claps their hands, just say "No".

Comment: "I can't think of a single good reason for "Use Ctrl+Click to follow hyperlinks" to be a preference."  This is handy when you want to edit the display text of a hyperlink without accidentally following it.  Otherwise, you have to select outside of the link and maneuver with the arrow keys, or navigate the context menu to edit the hyperlink.  Removing preferences because you personally don't see the use case is not good ux.

Comment: @CarlKevinson That's the opposite as far as I remember. With the preference enabled, you have to hold CTRL while clicking to follow, otherwise you will select/edit. I don't see any use case for the behavior you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To a point, I've tried to do this already - we refuse a lot more user requests than we put in. Even with this however, the number of sensible options can easily reach a huge number, and saying "no" to a good, useful customisation just because you feel you've run out of space in your options dialog seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Microsoft Word indeed becomes very awkward to use if you disable the "Use Ctrl+Click to follow hyperlinks" option. Then you will accidentally follow hyperlinks when you edit text. But I suppose people who mostly use Word to *read* documents might want to disable it.

Comment: Accidentally following hyperlinks can even be a horrible security risk in some cases.

Comment: People use software for different things. Microsoft Word in particular caters to an extremely broad user base. "Smart" functionality is, in general, likely to be tuned to writing straightforward English prose and might be unhelpful for typing poetry, or lab reports. Consider smart quotes, for example: they're not very smart at all if I want to write about a programming language. So Word's defaults can cater to what 95% of people want 95% of the time, and preferences try to make everyone else happy.

Comment: "If they're really smart, why on Earth would I want to disable them?" because they usually only work for the use case they were invented for. But user bases can be quite broad. Take the "smart" Auto-Format of MS Word for example. its good when you write your general 0815 letter. Its awful if you write poetry, certain technical documents, or want to get creative when building insane birthday cards. So you definitely want to be able to disable it when needed.

Answer (score 2):

A modern solution could leverage a neural network, trained with various commands and the associated menu items. Think about how Cortana, Siri, Alexa, Omega, and Google function. You type in a command or speak something, and your device does it for you (or at least pulls up the place where you can do it). You can offer an "Advanced" menu for people who want to just find their items in the normal manner (category/sub-category/items). Given your example, a user could say "I want to disable tracking", and the neural network would divine that they are looking for the Do Not Track flag.

Even if you're using an omnibox sort of solution, like Google Chrome, simply implementing a neural network can give the users a better experience, especially if they allow uploading anonymous usage statistics. For example, a few users type in "disable tracking" and then clicked on Do Not Click, so this would be trained in to the neural network. Over time, as more anonymous statistics were collected, the options dialog would actually get smarter the more the users interacted with the options dialog.

Even without crowd-sourcing your data, you could still pre-train the neural network with multiple phrases/keywords for each menu item, and as each user starts using the menu system, the options dialog would eventually be tailored for their specific use patterns. The entire point is that the menu could learn from how its used, rather than forcing users to learn how to use the software. There would still be something of a learning curve, but I think the eventual end goal would be worth the effort.

Comment: Neural networks for an options dialog isn't something I'd heard / considered before, and probably something that's a bit too involved for me to get into specifically - but I like the out of the box thinking!

Comment: Are you reinventing [Clippy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Assistant)?

Comment: @meriton Clippy was a terrible implementation of a good idea. Neural networks and AI have reached the point where Clippy 2018 (if it were a thing) could actually increase productivity. Unfortunately, Microsoft instead went with their retarded "ribbon menu". But I am looking forward to a menu that configures itself based on your habits, rather than forcing you to figure out how it's supposed to work. I can dream, can't I?

Comment: @phyrfox - it would be nice to dream of a world where we don't use "retarded" to refer to something we don't like, either. On a board like this, that is, at the least unprofessional, and also insulting.

Answer (score 2):

Without reinventing the wheel or blowing up the idea of Preferences dialog box, I think the single most user-friendly improvement is to have an area within the options dialog box where a paragraph-long explanation of each option appears when you select it or hover on it. One of the things that makes Preferences difficult is trying to cram the explanation for a program-wide change into a few words. "Enable Smart Quotes" is easy to understand, but even it could benefit from a longer explanation. I've admired the way Adobe in some programs implemented in-depth Preference explanations.

Comment: The issue I have with this is that it requires hovering over each option to find out what it actually does - this is fine if you want to find out what one particular option does, but if you're trying to discover what option does something, hovering over each one in turn is a pain.

Comment: Does not have to be a hover. If it's possible to move the selection bar in the topic tree with keyboard arrow keys, and to tab to set the focus on each option on each page, you can press one key to change pages, and press Tab to read each option's long description. Of course the most user friendly would be to have all that information also be searchable in online help.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, there are really only three major goals in an Options menu:

1. Find what you want quickly and with as little exploration as possible.
2. Understand what a given option does as easily as possible, preferably without resorting to dedicated Help windows or web-searches.
3. Make changing the option as clear and direct as possible. (usually a given, you can't go too far wrong with a tickbox)

The first task, finding what you're looking for is one of the most variable I've seen, some systems present you with a wall of options with some organisation by category or even alphabetically.
Some provide only a questionaire-style FAQ system.
Search boxes are popular because it allows for natural-language queries.

Personally I'm most comfortable drilling down by category until I find the one place that has exactly what I need.
I believe that a system should support someone searching, but it also needs to be quick for someone who knows exactly what they're doing. No need for a quiz or natural-language search when you already know how to get where you're going.

A good Options menu will have natural-language search, but also lay out all the options in a navigable fashion, clearly organised by function. The human mind is built to visualise locations, not key-phrases. So a mappable menu is very intuitive.
If I make a search, it should show me the results, I select one, it navigates there and I can *see* where I am in the menus on a side-bar.

If I then want to find that place again, I can navigate quickly through the side-bar until I get there, or I can use a History system to find my previous searches.

The second major task of comprehension is rather simpler.
Provide a plain-text explanation of functionality with a link to a more in-depth explanation if they need it.
I suggest using the common convention of a ? symbol in a circular button, this can reveal a floating textbox which has the full explanation, either when clicked or when rolled over.

Beyond that, clear partitioning and use of iconography will be of great help.

Associating the specific options with buttons the user is already familiar with (eg: the ones in the main UI of the application) will help them find what they want too.

For an example, if I'm looking for an option to affect Fonts in a word-processor, I will be greatly assisted by seeing the Font button's icon in the Options menu and being able to follow that.

One could also add a context-sensitive options system into the UI itself.
So if I right-click a button in the main UI, it should include a link to the appropriate section of the Options window in a context-menu. Instantly doing away with the need to navigate from any sort of landing page.

Further to that, adding buttons for toggling the most common changes (either by that user, or from anonymous usage data) to that same context menu would also be of great help.

Comment: My favorite example of an incomprehensible option is in Excel's Advanced options. There's one: "Cursor Movement" with two radio buttons: "Logical" and "Visual". What behavior do these change? When are visual and logical movement different? And why do searches in the help for "cursor movement" or "logical visual" or "cursor movement logical visual" all give results that do not appear to apply? *(Note: one of the results* does *apply, but you'll only recognize it if you* **already** *know what the option does.)*

Comment: Exactly, a system conforming to the guidelines I laid out would explain in plain words exactly what Logical or Visual will achieve, and searches for that functionality would turn it up because the description includes the appropriate keywords.